# Interactive papers

Tags: mathematics, reference-request

I have been working on a mathematics paper for some time now, and I had the idea that instead of publishing just a regular paper, I could create something that is "interactive" to encourage a reader to engage with the concepts, and facilitate understanding. My criteria for "interaction" are the following:

1. There should be visible *movement* in the paper itself
2. The reader should have the ability to control some aspect of this movement.

I will still decide exactly how this can be used to make the reading experience easier, but for now I would just like to know if this is something that is commonly done, and if so. If anyone has any pointers or links, on how to get started.

Comment: My understanding is that papers are "old-fashioned" by convention, and very technical by intention; so an interactive format wouldn't be very popular. But interactive blog posts and "demos" are *amazing* and very popular, even in academia. It's very common to publish a technical paper and accompanying blog post and/or demo, I suggest you do that but make the blog and/or demo interactive.

Comment: i.e. a jupyter notebook accompanying your paper?

Comment: Don't do it! Any method you use will be obsolete in 5-10 years and/or will rely on a server that won't be online then, and then your work will be lost to science. By all means make an interactive demo, but keep it separate from the paper and don't make the paper rely on it.

Comment: @N.Virgo to be honest - I usually don't bother hunting for papers that are not available digitially. So if you used the medium "print" 20 years ago, and nobody likes your stuff enough to write about it in a book or scan it. Guess what: your method of publishing is obsolete and lost to science. And this is what always happens if nobody bothers transferring stuff from the old medium to the new medium. And given how much content is available in html form on the web I highly doubt that html will be obsolete in 5-10 year without an excellent way to transfer to the potential new medium.

Comment: @FelixB. I think you're over-optimistic. I'd be surprised if you can find a website that is (i) 5 years old or more, (ii) interactive, (iii) not actively maintained, (iv) still online, and (v) still works. If you go to 10 years the task will be basically impossible, because almost any interactive web site from that era was made in Adobe Flash.

Comment: I already did: https://distill.pub/about/ (started in 2016, check (i), on hiatus since 2021 so (iii),  and obviously works and is online). Since it was a journal and gave out DOIs they pretty much promised to keep that running indefinitely. Okay this is a bit tongue in cheek, but I think the point is: *Don't self publish* (neither in print nor interactively). If you do, nobody except you feels responsible for keeping it accessible, which is essentially a guarantee for it to become unavailable. But that does not mean don't do something interactive

Comment: @FelixB. I think "on indefinite hiatus since 2021" is a fairly good indicator that articles published in that journal will stop working as web technology moves on. They might continue to maintain them for some time, but reading the text about the hiatus I get the impression of a small group of people whose enthusiasm has already waned, so I wouldn't expect that maintenance effort to continue indefinitely. (And that was my point above: for anything interactive to exist indefinitely, someone will need to maintain it indefinitely, until we have an interactive platform that's as stable as pdf.)

Comment: @N.Virgo that maintenance effort is orders of magnitudes lower than the reviewing/advising effort for new papers. Given that they already invested this time, I doubt that they would not care about it continuing to run. And while reviewing of articles requires experts, keeping it running can be done by any CS intern. So as long as there is funding for that it is going to be around, which I am pretty sure will be forever (I can't imagine that a doi doesn't have any more strings attached than a normal website btw).

Comment: @FelixB. 'I usually don't bother hunting for papers that are not available digitially. So if you used the medium "print" 20 years ago, and nobody likes your stuff enough to write about it in a book or scan it ... your method of publishing is obsolete and lost to science.' I hope you don't really believe this. Many people do still go to libraries. Maybe you don't bother, but other people do.

Comment: @toby544 in the areas I am interested in, there is enough literature, that you can't read everything anyway. And if it is more difficult to access I usually have alternatives available. And it is a lot less fun to read typewriter equations than LaTeX equations so I certainly have a bias for more recent literature. Most of the time there is a scan available anyway, only books were ever a problem and then there were always alternatives so yeah...

Comment: @FelixB. OK. That is a more sensible and moderate statement than "your method of publishing is obsolete and lost to science." In my areas too there is enough literature that you can't read everything, and alternatives are usually available. But I have still got many useful bits of information by going to libraries.

Comment: @toby544 the point I am making is: I don't really read print. Which means, for everything I am reading, someone has made the effort to digitalize it. It is reasonable to assume a similar kind of preservations effort for things which got a DOI assigned to them. I wanted to express, that a method being obsolete (e.g. paper) doesn't mean that the content will be.

Comment: @FelixB. I can understand that you don't read print, but apart from that it is hard to understand the point of your last comment, especially the last sentence. And it is completely wrong to say that paper is "obsolete" - that word is very strong and refers to a thing's status in the whole of society, not just a tendency or one person's preference. Typewriters are obsolete but paper is not.

Answer (score 19):

There was such a journal for machine learning:
https://distill.pub/about/. But it was put on [indefinite hiatus](https://distill.pub/2021/distill-hiatus/) due to burnout of the editorial team.

### Format problem

Perhaps most generally you have the problem of choosing a format. LaTeX is the standard in mathematics, but it is not suited for interactivity. This immediately puts you into the position of having to use non-standard tools to create your paper. Using non-standard tools generally leads to more effort.

For example you might decide to use `html` as it is very suited for interactivity, but then you have to figure out how you

- cite stuff (as most of the citation machinery, `bibtex` or `biblatex` is geared towards LaTeX). Of course you could do citations manually but then you have a ton of extra work.
- how to actually write equations. Html doesn't have machinery for maths, so you will end up either with MathML (would not recommended) or MathJax, KaTeX-like javascript libraries. Dealing with that is overhead.
- how you convert it back to pdf to get a journal to accept it (which then also means you have to be able to style it for the journal. And the journal typically expects LaTeX so it will at best provide `.sty` files for tex)
- ...

Distill wrote some javascript code to enable citing, but it is mixed up with their format and should probably be factored out as a standalone library. I started an attempt once to create such a citation library ([bibcite](https://github.com/FelixBenning/bibcite)) but abandoned it (due to time constraints). It is working somewhat, but does not look good, links are broken at the moment and I never got around to creating hover overs.

### Related projects

- [LaTeXML](https://math.nist.gov/%7EBMiller/LaTeXML/) is an attempt to convert LaTeX to html automatically (their goal is to convert the entire arxiv to html cf. [ar5iv.org](https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/)). It is relatively brittle in my experience, and it is limited in the interactivity department as the origin is static latex (you can hook into it to make it add javascript though, for simple stuff like [collapisble proofs](https://github.com/brucemiller/LaTeXML/issues/1834#issuecomment-1079280087)).
- [PreTeXt](https://pretextbook.org/gallery.html) takes the other route, you have to write xml (which can then be converted into both LaTeX and html). People use it mostly for books (e.g. [Discrete Mathematics](https://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/preface.html)) the styling and layout looks a bit dated, but that could be fixed and they have good [support for interactivity](https://pretextbook.org/examples/sample-article/crc/section-interactive-authored.html). But they also have a custom cite style which does not work well with citation libraries like Zotero, which might be the reason people stay away from it for papers. At least I don't know of any papers using it. It is much more stable than LaTeXML since it forces you to use a stable XML sublanguage and there are validation files baked into an extension available for VSCode. Editing is still not as comfortable as LaTeX since there are no such things like synctex letting you jump to the code generating a specific part of the pdf. And the paragraph tags are quite annoying to be honest.
- [Manim](https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/) is a python library geared towards rendering math videos, which are generally not interactive so it probably does not suit you.
- Reactive notebooks like [Observable](https://observablehq.com/) (javascript) [Pluto.jl](https://github.com/fonsp/Pluto.jl) (julia) or with more tweaking [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) (mostly python, but also R and julia) allow some interactive plots. You could supply these as a supplemental with your paper. But chances are that few people will look into the supplemental much less get them running. Observable is probably you best bet as they are easier to host, so you could provide a link in the paper.
- Enhanced Markdown like [Quarto](https://quarto.org/) (which is based on the older R-Markdown, which only worked for R)
- Data Dashboard website makers like [Dash by Plotly](https://plotly.com/dash/) (python) and [R shiny](https://shiny.posit.co/)
- Perhaps this attempt ([typst](https://github.com/typst/typst)) at a LaTeX replacement will turn out a better foundation for interactivity in the future (although they do not exist at the time of writing - this is mostly a reminder for my future self)

### Conclusion

People are thinking about this problem. But since everyone is time constrained and there is probably very little funding to create tooling there is not much of a toolchain to create such a paper. And without the ability to easily create such papers, there aren't enough papers to fill a journal so I wouldn't expect there to be one (I certainly do not know of one).

Comment: Regarding citations when not using LaTeX: LaTeX is the standard in mathematics, but it is not the standard in all fields that heavily use citations. So there have been quite a lot of tools that have been developed to help with citations and bibliography, and many of these tools work regardless of which software you use to write the paper (even including bare word processors).

Comment: See for instance [Wikipedia: Comparison of reference management software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_reference_management_software)

Comment: @Stef sure, but those other fields will generally not use html but Microsoft Word perhaps. And Word is ill suited for interactive papers as well. At least I am not aware of any field using html for papers. And I doubt that there is any if not even computer science does that.

Comment: @FelixB. Many journals which allow to view an article in html rather than as pdf, see e.g. https://journals.aps.org/prx/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevX.13.041008#fulltext As of now the authors still submit the paper in Latex or Word, and then it's converted in some – probably semi-automatic – way by the editors. Primary strength of Latex is organizing text on paper pages, which a dying medium. I would think that ability to generate html from Latex might actually save it from obsolescence.

Answer (score 14):

A possibility would be to provide, in addition to the paper, code that the readers could interact with. URL to the code could be provided directly into the paper (i.e. in a "Data availability" section). Depending on the editors and the journal, the code could be hosted either by the journal (e.g. as a "Supplementary Information") or independently on a GitHub repo. If you are providing code in Python, an interesting solution is to organize it as a notebook, which allows to separate sections that the readers can modify and play around with from these that should not be modified. Other alternatives exist for other languages. As an example, I am thinking about this [tutorial on Kalman Filtering](https://github.com/rlabbe/Kalman-and-Bayesian-Filters-in-Python), which can be read as a classical textbook but also includes a lot of interactivity via notebooks.

Comment: Really good answer